# Как реализовать смену положения блоков при адаптивной верстке на bootstrap?

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

В качестве изучения адаптивной вёрстки на `bootstrap`, хочу реализовать поведение блоков как на сайте http://aplle.com в шапке навигации. В принципе могу реализовать на костылях, сам, эксперментируя с `media` запросами в собственной таблице стилей. Но всё же интересует как это осуществить красиво, с помощью классов `navbar`.

[image: полный экран]

[image: мобильная версия]

А теперь вопросы.

1. Если все пункты в полном экране, реализовать в качестве списка, то при создании кнопки меню, будет прятаться весь список. Как сделать так что бы прятались все элементы кроме крайнего левого и правого?

   2. Как переместить кнопку меню, влево, яблоко в центр, и bag  вправо. Только ручками, или тоже есть на это какие то уже готовые бутстраповские классы?
      Ручками как это делать знаю. Интересует именно реализация, с помощью  `bootstrap`.

Мой код:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>   
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ipad</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Iphone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bag</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Как можно будет увидеть все элементы прячутся, под кнопку и кнопка по умолчанию прижимается к правому краю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать следующее.

1. Первому и последнему элементам списка задать класс hidden-xs, что-бы они прятались при маленьком размере экрана.
2. Добавить перед кнопкой две ссылки apple и bag с классами visible-xs, что бы они отображались только при маленьком размере экрана
3. для перемещения кнопки к левому краю экрана прописываем ей класс pull-left
4. для перемещения кнопки bag к правому краю, прописываем ей класс pull-right
5. яблоко непосредственно можно отцентрировать только в кастомном css

Спасибо англоязычному stack-overflow

http://output.jsbin.com/hijuzet
Пример.

Answer (score 0):

У bootstrap красивых решений ваших вопросов нет. Вам придется ручками и костылями делать. Самое правильное решение это -красивые костыли :)

Comment: Очень информативно...

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade Вопрос был задан как это реализовать именно с помощью bootstrap. Ответ дан что ни как. Я лично таких возможностей в bootstrap не нашел. Если Вы знаете как это сделать без костылей то ваш ответ будет более информативным ;)